# Getting all related data from many-to-many table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

This is my select to obtain all data of `Table2` from M-M table. All I have to obtain data from tables is `ID_TABLE1_FK=3` value.

```
    Select s1.* from TABLE2 s1 
    JOIN TABLE3 s2 ON s2.ID_TABLE2_FK = s1.ID_TABLE2_PK
    WHERE s2.ID_TABLE1_FK=3;

   'this query returns me data from table1 same way - I need to combine
   'them both in 1 row, that is desired output
    Select a1.* from TABLE1 a1 
    JOIN TABLE3 s2 ON s2.ID_TABLE1_FK = a1.ID_TABLE1_PK
    WHERE s2.ID_TABLE1_FK=3;
```

Now I want to obtain all data from `Table1` as well, in the same query. How?

These are my table designs:

```
    M-M table:
    ID_TABLE3_PK
    ID_TABLE1_FK
    ID_TABLE2_FK

    TABLE1:
    ID_TABLE1_PK
    Name
    Surname

    TABLE2:
    ID_TABLE2_PK
    Street
    Address

DESIRED OUTPUT (with only ID_TABLE1_FK=3):

Name,Surname,Street,Address
```

Comment: @Moudiz, no. TABLE3  joins records from Table1 and Table2, with ID. And I want all data from those 2 tables, using just ID_TABLE1_FK. Is It possible ?

Comment: what about this ?

Select s1.* from TABLE2 s1 
JOIN TABLE3 s2 ON s2.ID_TABLE2_FK = s1.ID_TABLE2_PK
JOIN TABLE1 s3 ON s3.ID_TABLE2_FK = s1.ID_TABLE2_PK
WHERE s2.ID_TABLE1_FK=3;

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please provide a small example of data and needed result?

Comment: @Moudiz, you probably meant this : Select s1.* from TABLE2 s1 
JOIN TABLE3 s2 ON s2.ID_TABLE2_FK = s1.ID_TABLE2_PK 
***JOIN TABLE1 s3 ON s2.ID_TABLE2_FK = s1.ID_TABLE2_PK*** 
WHERE s2.ID_TABLE1_FK=3...But unfortunally It returns me data from Table2 only. Your query doesn't return anything.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 can you provid us simple data and required result ? as aleksej suggested

Comment: @Aleksej, my tables have many fields, I rather not show an example of them. It's not so hard to understand actually - both tables have ID's same, I just need to return all fields from both tables in 1 row. But I will add second query to my question to see what must be combined together.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve]. It's not necessary that you post you actual table, you can build a simplified test case to help us in helping you

Comment: @Aleksej, I edited my question for desired output, is this ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join both `table1` and `table2` on `table3`:

```
SELECT s1.*, a1.* 
FROM   TABLE2 s1 
JOIN   TABLE3 s2 ON s2.ID_TABLE2_FK = s1.ID_TABLE2_PK
JOIN   TABLE1 a1 ON s2.ID_TABLE1_FK = a1.ID_TABLE1_PK
WHERE  s2.ID_TABLE1_FK=3;
```

Comment: thanks, that worked !! Damn, I was so close, all I did differently was doing ***"a"*** instead "a1.*" in the beginning of select :)